# Java JSCH - how to use tmux & shell?

Tags: java, shell, exec, jsch

I'm using JSCH to ssh to an external with Java. As of right now, my JSCH code looks like this:

```
JSch jsch = new JSch();
Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
session.setPassword(pass);  

java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties(); 
config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
session.setConfig(config);

session.connect(5000);

Channel channel = session.openChannel("shell");
channel.connect();          

input.add(command);
```

(with input.add eventually writing my command to an OutputStream).

The code works, but the problem is that the output looks strange.

> [m[?1l>(B)0[H[J[1;1H[22:40:53] [Server thread/INFO]:  what[K

rather than just

> [22:40:53] [Server thread/INFO]:  what

If I use exec rather than shell, I'll get the latter output, however, I can't use tmux with exec because tmux needs a pseudo terminal. I've tried both exec and shell with every combination of setPty (true and false) and I still can't seem to get output that doesn't have weird symbols, works with tmux, and doesn't close the outputstream when it's not receiving anything.